# OpenLayers overview shows wrong map

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

i have a problem. I have to implement a map with OpenLayers.

As BaseLayer I use an external WMTS-Service, which has the projection EPSG:25832. I want to have an OverviewMap, but the OverviewMap doesn't show the same Map like the Main one...i suspect the problem happens because of the weird projection the WMTS gives me.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OverviewMap map options must be passed through `mapOptions` parameter:

```
var navi_div = document.getElementById('div_navigation');
var overview = new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap({
    mapOptions: mapOptions,
    //projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:25832"),
    maximized: true,
    maximizeTitle: 'Show the overview map',
    minimizeTitle: 'Hide the overview map',
    div: navi_div
});
```

See a demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Yt3EH/1/